# joining and grouping and counting two javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I try to get an object like:

```
var result = [{ "surveyCode":"C", "count": 1}, {"surveyCode":"A", count: 4}]
```

by joining the two objects on surveyCode and counting the items in object a for each selected surveyCode.

I also can't link a map after merge. Any thoughts?

My attempt is:

```js
var a = [{"id":319268,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 4},
    {"id":319269,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 4},
    {"id":268393,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 4},
    {"id":319266,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 5},
    {"id":319267,"surveyCode":"C", "field3": 4},
    {"id":319267,"surveyCode":"B", "field3": 5}];
    
var b = [{"surveyCode":"C"},{"surveyCode":"A"}]

var merge = function() {
  var obj = {},
    i = 0,
    il = arguments.length,
    key;
  for (; i < il; i++) {
    for (key in arguments[i]) {
      if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key] = arguments[i][key];
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

function groupBy(data, property) {
  return data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = 0;
    }
    acc[key]++;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};


var allGroupedBySurveyCode = groupBy(a, 'surveyCode'); // returns [{ "A": 4}, {"B":1}, {"C": 1}]
var keepOnlyJoinedSurveyCodes = merge(c, allGroupedBySurveyCode); // doesn't work - expects common key e.g. surveyCode, not A.
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Where is `c`?

Answer (score 1):

You could count the occurance of `surveyCode` and map the count by the grouped array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 319268, surveyCode: "A", field3: 4 }, { id: 319269, surveyCode: "A", field3: 4 }, { id: 268393, surveyCode: "A", field3: 4 }, { id: 319266, surveyCode: "A", field3: 5 }, { id: 319267, surveyCode: "C", field3: 4 }, { id: 319267, surveyCode: "B", field3: 5 }],
    groups = [{ surveyCode: "C" }, { surveyCode: "A" }],
    counts = data.reduce((r, { surveyCode }) => (r[surveyCode] = (r[surveyCode] || 0) + 1, r), {}),
    result = groups.map(({ surveyCode }) => ({ surveyCode, count: counts[surveyCode] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.map` and `Array.reduce` to count the number of data

```js
const a = [{
    id: 319268,
    surveyCode: 'A',
    field3: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 319269,
    surveyCode: 'A',
    field3: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 268393,
    surveyCode: 'A',
    field3: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 319266,
    surveyCode: 'A',
    field3: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 319267,
    surveyCode: 'C',
    field3: 4,
  }
];

const b = [{
  surveyCode: 'C',
}, {
  surveyCode: 'A',
}];

// We are going to create a new array named "count"
// the array will have the same number of entry as 'b'
// Array.map will loop on every item of the 'b' array and execute a function
// the result of the function for each entry will be the entry of the 
// new array
const count = b.map(x => ({
  // we copy all the key of the 'b' entry on the new element
  ...x,

  // we are going to count the number of time the surveyCode is
  // present on the 'a' array, for this we use of Array.reduce
  // Array.reduce will start with a value and loop on every entry of 'a'
  // What we do is simple, is the surveyCode the same ?
  // > yes? count +1, > no? count +0
  count: a.reduce((tmp, {
    surveyCode,
  }) => (surveyCode === x.surveyCode ? tmp + 1 : tmp), 0),
}));

console.log(count);
```

---

**Irrelevant** :

When you are coding in es6+ try to be consistent. Use of `const` and `let` instead of `var` which is legacy javascript. The use of `Array.reduce` tells me that you are not coding legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Any issue using lodash?
I'd probably reach straight for:
https://lodash.com/docs/#countBy

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could map over the survey codes and count each entry in `a` for that particular survey code. Code would look something like this

```js
const a = [
  {id: 319268, surveyCode: 'A', field3: 4},
  {id: 319269, surveyCode: 'A', field3: 4},
  {id: 268393, surveyCode: 'A', field3: 4},
  {id: 319266, surveyCode: 'A', field3: 5},
  {id: 319267, surveyCode: 'C', field3: 4},
  {id: 319267, surveyCode: 'B', field3: 5}
];

const b = [{surveyCode: 'C'}, {surveyCode: 'A'}];

const result = b.map((item) => {
  return {...item, count: a.filter(({surveyCode}) => surveyCode === item.surveyCode).length};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using reduce.

- Loop over data, filter data based on array `b` and `property`
- Check if passed property from current element is present on op or not, if present increase count by 1 else set it with desired value and then increase count by 1
- Take the values

```js
var a = [{"id":319268,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 4},
{"id":319269,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 4},
{"id":268393,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 4},
{"id":319266,"surveyCode":"A", "field3": 5},
{"id":319267,"surveyCode":"C", "field3": 4},
{"id":319267,"surveyCode":"B", "field3": 5}];


function groupBy(data, property) {
  var b = [{ "surveyCode": "C" }, { "surveyCode": "A" }].map(v => v[property])
  let filteredData = data.filter(v => b.includes(v[property]))

  return Object.values(filteredData.reduce((op, inp) => {
    op[inp[property]] = op[inp[property]] || {
      [property]: inp[property],
      count: 0
    }
    op[inp[property]].count++
      return op
  }, {}))
}

console.log(groupBy(a, 'surveyCode'))
```

Comment: Downvoter leaving a comment behind will help me learn in case i missed something in my answer.

Comment: yep I sometimes have the feeling that some answers are only voted down to make their own answer appear at the top for gathering further upvotes xD